# which data type is support more string/characters then CLOB

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

Currently I used CLOB for storing definition of an stored procedures for all_objects but some procedure length are long so it is very difficult to excute using Excute Immediate as it cross lenghth inw hile using CLOB

> > ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error
> >     06502. 00000 -  "PL/SQL: numeric or value error%s"
> >     *Cause:    An arithmetic, numeric, string, conversion, or constraint error
> >                occurred. For example, this error occurs if an attempt is made to
> >                assign the value NULL to a variable declared NOT NULL, or if an
> >                attempt is made to assign an integer larger than 99 to a variable
> >                declared NUMBER(2).
> >     *Action:   Change the data, how it is manipulated, or how it is declared so
> >                that values do not violate constraints.

```
DECLARE
    v_output   CLOB := NULL;
    a          CLOB := NULL;
    srce       VARCHAR2(1000) := NULL;
BEGIN
   -- Note,we don't search for package bodies. We will extract the body
   -- along with the package spec.
    dbms_output.put_line('Database DDL For Selected Objects Report');
    FOR dd IN (
        SELECT
            object_name,
            status
        FROM
            all_objects
        WHERE
                status != 'VALID'
            AND
                object_name LIKE '%SP_RPT%'
    ) LOOP
        a := '';
        srce := dd.object_name;
        dbms_output.put_line(srce || ' proceudure creation start');
        FOR dd1 IN (
            SELECT
                text
            FROM
                dba_source
            WHERE
                    type = 'PROCEDURE'
                AND
                    name LIKE dd.object_name
        ) LOOP
-- DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (dd1.text);
            a := a || dd1.text;
     --       DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (a);
        END LOOP;

        dbms_output.put_line(a);
   --  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE a ;
        dbms_output.put_line(srce || ' proceudure Updated successfully');
    END LOOP;

EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        dbms_output.put_line('ERROR occured while creating Procedure ' || srce);
        dbms_output.put_line(a);
        dbms_output.put_line(substr(
            dbms_utility.format_error_stack
             || ' ,'
             || dbms_utility.format_error_backtrace,
            1,
            500
        ) );

        RAISE;
END;
```

Comment: [EXECUTE IMMEDIATE](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/executeimmediate_statement.htm#LNPLS01317) accepts `CLOB` statements, so there should be no problem. The limit for CLOB depends on your Database Block Size and vary from 8 TB to 128 TB - I doubt that one could ever exceed this limit.

Comment: thanks @WernfriedDomscheit i too surprised let me share code and error

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit could you p,lese check comments in answer 1 and let me know your feeds

Comment: Having just an error message is not helpful. What is your code? For sure the issue it not due to length in case of CLOB.

Comment: getting error on dbms_output.put_line(a); this line

Comment: @SiddharthJain dbms_output will not give you this issue. DBMS_OUTPUT can give you "ORU-10027: buffer overflow, limit of 1000000 bytes" this error. I am suspecting that  "srce := dd.object_name" this line can give you error. From your exception block can you tell us the value of "srce" when you are getting error. dbms_output.put_line('ERROR occured while creating Procedure ' || srce);

Comment: @AnkitMongia the value of src i am geeting 
SP_RPT_GET_ASSETRPT proceudure creation start
ERROR occured while creating Procedure SP_RPT_GET_ASSETRPT
above two are values for srce in different cases

Comment: @SiddharthJain is it  also possible for you to share code of this procedure

Comment: @AnkitMongia it is difficuitlt to share SP code but i can tell you its of 1366 rows
is it specific chracters which can cause problem like % etc
because when i print dd1.text iget all the rows which will get print on DBMS output console

Comment: @SiddharthJain can you please comment the exception part of your code and run it, just see at which line you are getting error.

Comment: @AnkitMongia it is working without error but with exception why it is giving error then could you please help

Comment: @SiddharthJain you mean by  commenting exception part its running , but after adding exception part its throwing error ?

Comment: @AnkitMongia yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try it like this:

```
FOR dd1 IN (SELECT text FROM dba_source WHERE ... ORDER BY LINE) LOOP
    a := a || dd1.text ||CHR(13);
END LOOP;
```

However, what is the purpose of this? Most likely a simple

```
FOR dd IN (
    SELECT object_name, object_type, status
    FROM all_objects
    WHERE status != 'VALID'
        AND object_name LIKE '%SP_RPT%') 
LOOP
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER '||dd.object_type||' '||dd.object_name||' COMPILE';
    if dd.object_type = 'PACKAGE BODY' THEN
       EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER '||dd.object_type||' '||dd.object_name||' COMPILE BODY';
    END IF;
END LOOP;
```

would do the same.

Answer (score 2):

***execute_immediate_statement***

*dynamic_sql_stmt*

*String literal, string variable, or string expression that represents a SQL statement. Its type must be either CHAR, VARCHAR2, or CLOB.*

Reference : https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/executeimmediate_statement.htm#LNPLS01317

Also for more information related to data type size and usage refer  : https://sqljana.wordpress.com/2017/02/07/oracle-clob-vs-varchar2-when-when-not-to-use/

I suggest CLOB is a better choice in your case.

Comment: Is there any issues if a print CLOB variable wirth DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line
as some times it print and some times it give error

Comment: ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error
06502. 00000 -  "PL/SQL: numeric or value error%s"
*Cause:    An arithmetic, numeric, string, conversion, or constraint error
           occurred. For example, this error occurs if an attempt is made to
           assign the value NULL to a variable declared NOT NULL, or if an
           attempt is made to assign an integer larger than 99 to a variable
           declared NUMBER(2).
*Action:   Change the data, how it is manipulated, or how it is declared so
           that values do not violate constraints.

Comment: @Siddharth Jain DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line works well with CLOB so dont think issue is related to same.

Comment: did you check th above code what error might be i am getting because it pointing at dbmsoutput line only